# the redirect does not execute after the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The topic exists on stackoverflow, but I still can't solve my problem.

The user is in the `locking` page, when he clicks on a button, he must be redirected to the `select-portfolio` page.

When I am in the `lock` page, and I click on the button, there is no redirect. Nothing is happening....

And I have no error in browser console.

I don't know how to solve this problem?

```
constructor(private service: LockingService, private router: Router, ) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.locking();
}

locking(): void {

    this.service.getLocking().pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {

        }

    });


}

redirect() {
    this.router.navigate(['/administrations/views/select-portfolio']);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code gets through the redirect() method? try adding some logging to the console there.

Comment: Hi @amelabamelab440, can you please share your app.routing and html files !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it will help you or not you can try with the router URL like

```
redirect() {
    this.router.navigate([this.router.url + '/administrations/views/select-portfolio']);
}
```